# Getting template error while templating string when trying to work with json and json_query filter

Tags: parsing, ansible, json-query

I try to execute this ansible command :

```
 ansible localhost -m debug -a "var={{ db_config| to_json |json_query(*)}}" \
       -e 'db_config=[{"name":"mydb1","services":["app1","app2"]},{"name":"mydb12","services":["app1"]}]'
```

To get all json elements using json_query(*)
but I'm  getting the following error :

```
 fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: 'template error while templating string: expected token ''end of print statement'', got ''name''. String: {{"[{\\"name\\":\\"mydb1\\",\\"services\\":[\\"app1\\",\\"app2\\"]},{\\"name\\":\\"mydb12\\",\\"services\\":[\\"app1\\"]}]"}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in this single one liner:

1. The parameter to use for debug in your case is `msg` (to output the result of a template or static value) and not `var` (used to debug a single var without any transformation). See the [debug module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html)
2. You are passing as a parameter a json string representation. The filter you want to use is `from_json` (to transform your string to a dict/list) and not `to_json` (which does the exact opposite).
3. Your [jmespath expression](https://jmespath.org/examples.html) in `json_query` is invalid for two reason:

   - It's not a string (just a bare wildcard caracter)
   - Even quoted it would not respect the specification (follow the above link).

The following fixed one liner gives the result (I believe...) you expect:

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a 'msg={{ db_config | from_json | json_query("[]") }}' \
-e 'db_config=[{"name":"mydb1","services":["app1","app2"]},{"name":"mydb12","services":["app1"]}]'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "mydb1",
            "services": [
                "app1",
                "app2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "mydb12",
            "services": [
                "app1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that you can even drop the json decoding step by passing your arguement as a full inlined json:

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a 'msg={{ db_config | json_query("[]") }}' \
-e '{"db_config":[{"name":"mydb1","services":["app1","app2"]},{"name":"mydb12","services":["app1"]}]}'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "mydb1",
            "services": [
                "app1",
                "app2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "mydb12",
            "services": [
                "app1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I suspect you are trying all this to later test `json_query` expressions to select your data.

- You should be aware there a lot of other core filters in ansible (among which `selectattr`, `rejectattr`, `select`, `reject`, `map`, `dict2items`, `items2dict`, `first`, `last`, `unique`, `zip`, `subelements`,...) that combined together can do most of the job `json_query` can do without its overhead (installing a python module and an ansible collection). `json_query` is only really needed for very complex queries.
- In case I am wrong and your final goal is really to display all elements of your input data, you can overly simplify. From the two examples above:

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a 'msg={{ db_config | from_json }}' \
-e 'db_config=[{"name":"mydb1","services":["app1","app2"]},{"name":"mydb12","services":["app1"]}]'

# OR (the next one can work with `var` for debug)

$ ansible localhost -m debug -a 'var=db_config' \
-e '{"db_config":[{"name":"mydb1","services":["app1","app2"]},{"name":"mydb12","services":["app1"]}]}'
```

Comment: you rae right my goal is to filter the json and json_query("[]") is just the starting point
the module is instaled on the server that is running the ansible task

Answer (score 0):

If you put the data into a file

```yaml
shell> cat test-data.yml
---
db_config:
  - {name: "mydb1", services: ["app1", "app2"]}
  - {name: "mydb12", services: ["app1"]}
```

and if you put the code into the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat test.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ db_config|json_query('[]') }}"
```

The command works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test.yml -e @test-data.yml
...
  msg:
  - name: mydb1
    services:
    - app1
    - app2
  - name: mydb12
    services:
    - app1
```